# My website won't let me scroll down far enough, cuts off part of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm working on making myself a personal website and on one of my tabs I have a png of my resume.  The problem is only about the top 2/3 of the png is actually visible. I've tried messing with the height and overflow and a few other things of body and that img but I can't seem to fix it or find anything on the web.  I know it's probably something simple but I can't figure it out and its getting frustrating. Here is a link to my site http://adamphillips.us

Here is my code for the png:

```
<section class="tab-item-3">
   <div class="download">
      <a href="Images/Adam_Phillips_Resume.pdf" target="_blank">Download my resume as a PDF file.</a>
   </div>       
   <div class="resume"> 
        <img src="Images/resume.png" alt="Resume">
   </div>
</section>
```

And Here is my css for it:

```
.resume img {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: medium solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you start designing your page(using CSS). Always give some properties to `body`.

So the **actual reason** here is you have `overflow:hidden` for `.tab-content` and no `height` property given to `body`.

**To Do:**

i) Add 2 properties to `body`.

ii) Remove 1 property from `.tab-content`.

Try this and it will work like charm.

```
body
{
    height:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.tab-content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px; 
    /* JUST REMOVE OVERFLOW PROPERTY
    overflow:hidden
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you; exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

do it...you can change in this class from old height to this new height

```css
.clear-backend{
    height: 1550px;
}
```

Comment: yes other way you can remove `overflow:hidden` from id `tab-content`

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div id='tab-content'>` has `overflow:hidden`. As the name suggests, this will hide the overflow. Delete overflow and the page will let you scroll down to see the rest of the image.

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine. try it

```
.resume{
        height: 1650px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: increase height to fit image completely in div